# "Add" appears to be working in WebFlux, but seems like there must be a "more accepted way"

Tags: functional-programming, httpresponse, spring-webflux

New to WebFlux, reactive, and handlers.

I am able to get a Mono<> from a ServerRequest and process the contained POJO to add a new tuple to a database. But, it seems like there should be a "better" or "more accepted" way to write this code.

Any help/input with the code in *AccountRequestHandler* would be appreciated, especially with explanations of the rationale behind the recommend change(s).

Router implementation (stripped down to only "POST")...

```
@Configuration
public class AccountRequestRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(AccountRequestHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/v2"),
                   nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                      .andRoute(RequestPredicates.POST("/accounts"), requestHandler::addAccount)
                       ));
    }
}
```

Handler implementation...
The code where I'm actually doing the add, and then separately creating a *ServerResponse*, is what I'm focused on. It seems "clunky", especially since *AccountService.addAccount()* returns a Mono on completion.

```
@Component
public class AccountRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private mil.navy.ccop.service.accounts.account.AccountService accountService;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> addAccount(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(Account.class).flatMap(account -> {
                                                                        accountService.addAccount(account);
                                                                        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
                                                                    })
                                                .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest()
                                                                             .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                             .build(Mono.empty()));
    }
}
```

AccountService implementation (again, stripped down)...

```
@Service
class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accounts;

    public AccountService() {
    }

    public Mono<Void> addAccount(Account account) {
        Account proxy;

        // make sure that accountId is set to support auto-generation of synthetic key value
        proxy = new Account(-1, account.getShortName(), account.getLongName(), account.getDescription());
        accounts.save(proxy);
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

Appreciating all the help in ramping up on this style of programming....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well first of all, you have 2 addAccount, that can be a bit confusing.

Second of all, what kind of "repository" are you writing too? if its an sql repo you need to properly wrap it in a `Mono.fromCallable()` otherwise it will block the `Reactive` thread pool and you can have really bad performance.

Yes there are other ways of doing things. A lot of people tend to do things in `flatmap` or `map` and sure it is completely possible to do things here, but for the **semantics** i'd say it is less good.

`map` and `flatmap` are usually used to perform some sort of computation on the inner value of the mono and then return the same or a new value and or type inside the mono.

i would rewrite this like such.

return void here:

```
public void addAccount(Account account) {
    Account proxy;

    // make sure that accountId is set to support auto-generation of synthetic key value
    proxy = new Account(-1, account.getShortName(), account.getLongName(), account.getDescription());
    accounts.save(proxy);
}
```

And here:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> addAccount(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(Account.class)
                .doOnSuccess(account -> {
                            accountService.addAccount(account);
                }).then(ServerResponse.ok().build())
                  .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest()
                                      .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                      .build());
}
```

there are a number of different `doOn` methods that are ment to be used to consume and do "side effects" on things. Like `doOnSuccess`, `doOnError`, `doOnCancel` etc. etc.

you also have `then` and `thenReturn` which will just return whatever you put in them. `Then` returns whatever `Mono` you put in it. `thenReturn` wraps whatever value you put into it into a `Mono` and returns it.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I just need to sit down and really read through the Javadocs for Mono and Flux.

Comment: I am writing to a SQL (PostgreSQL) repo. I've been monitoring the R2DBC effort for PostgreSQL and will adopt that when it goes GA. However, I will look into your suggestion on Mono.fromCallable.

Comment: Curious as to why you recommend changing public Mono<Void> addAccount(Account) to public void addAccount(Account). Questioning because my intent is to, when it is released, adopt the R2DBC implementation for PostgreSQL, and I believe this will return mono's and flux's.

Comment: No special reason more than since it is a ”blocking” call its easier to deal with it as a ”non-reactive” method and keep the non-reactive code separated from the reactive code. I just picked the doOnSucess method of simplicity and that returns void so any method in it needs to return void. If you wrap your call in a Mono.fromCallable i think you need to return a mono like Mono<Void>

Comment: I like when code is selfexplanatory, it felt obvious for me when i wrote the example first get, then we we doOnSuccess, and after that we then return. But its more a code style then ”this is right, this is wrong”